# script bash or java code to delete in every file html of my folder a tag

Tags: java, bash

hi mate i have in my folder a lot of file html equal( the only difference is the string).
i want in every file html of my folder delete a tag.
an example of my file html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>P0001 Generic DTC: Fuel Volume Regulator Control Circuit/Open</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="P0001 diagnostic trouble code details." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="P0001, obd code, obd codes, diagnostic codes, trouble codes, diagnostic trouble codes, ford, gm, toyota, chrysler, dodge, nissan, chevy, dtc, dtcs, engine code, engine codes, check engine light" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/base.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/img/favicon.ico" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1196991-3']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body  class="results one">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"><a href="/">DTCSearch.com</a></div>
        <form action="/" method="post">
          <p>
            <input type="text" id="query" name="query" value="P0001"/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value=""/>
          </p>

        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="content">

<h1>P0001 OBD Trouble Code</h1>
<p>1 result found</p>


<div id="content-body">

  <table cellspacing="0" class="one">
    <caption>P0001 - Generic</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <td>Powertrain - Fuel and Air Metering - ISO/SAE Controlled</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <td><p>Fuel Volume Regulator Control Circuit/Open</p></td>
    </tr>



  </table>

  <p style="font-weight:bold">Try also: <a href="http://www.obd-codes.com/p0001" target="_blank">http://www.obd-codes.com/p0001</a></p>
</div>

      </div>
      <div id="footer">
   <div id="footer_banner">

<a href="http://affiliates.eautorepair.net/z/15/CD65/&dp=84"><img src="http://affiliates.eautorepair.net/42/65/15/&dp=84" alt="Do it Yourself Automobile Repair Information" border="0"></a>

   </div>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2008&ndash;2012 DTCSearch.com<br/>
        DTCSearch.com is hosted by <a href="http://www.scantool.net">ScanTool.net, LLC</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

i want to delete in every file this tag:

```
<a href="http://affiliates.eautorepair.net/z/15/CD65/&dp=84"><img src="http://affiliates.eautorepair.net/42/65/15/&dp=84" alt="Do it Yourself Automobile Repair Information" border="0"></a>
```

how do this ? tell me a solution with java or with bash or whit other tecnology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used:

```
sed -i 's#<a href="http://affiliates.eautorepair.net/z/15/CD65/&dp=84"><img src="http://affiliates.eautorepair.net/42/65/15/&dp=84" alt="Do it Yourself Automobile Repair Information" border="0"></a>##g' *
```

now i have a problem more serious. i want to delete

```
<p>
            <input type="text" id="query" name="query" value="XXXXX"/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value=""/>
          </p>
```

where xxxxx are 5 character different in every file . how can do ?

Comment: If you used Dogbane's answer might want to say so and accept that, and then ask a different question for your multiline, wildcard example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to delete a line from a file.

For example, the command:

```
sed '/foo/d' myfile
```

will delete all lines containing the word `foo` from `myfile`.

If you have multiple files you can run:

```
sed -i '/foo/d' *.html
```

The `-i` option tells `sed` to edit the files in-place.

Comment: this works if the html codes <a><img/></a>... are in same line.